# Importing Sublime/Atom code snippets with theme colors into InDesign or Illustrator

Tags: javascript, python, sublimetext3, atom-editor, adobe-indesign

What is the best way to import code snippets with the theme color from Sublime/Atom for a high-resolution poster?

Example code snippet: [JavaScript snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkznH.jpg)

Comment: Stackoverflow is for questions on programming, not posters, try asking on the [graphic design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange.

Answer (score 0):

I guess replicate it in illustrator?
I have doubt this is possible.

Figure out what font they are using and replicate your code would be a could solution.

Answer (score 0):

Export your code as PDF using a print package for [Atom](https://atom.io/packages/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=print) or [Sublime Text](https://packagecontrol.io/search/print)

Comment: [print-atom](https://atom.io/packages/print-atom) This works like a charm. Thank you!